# How to failover with keepalived only by success with vrrp_script , and not in any other case - such as reboot other node, stop service etc

Tags: keepalived

I try to setup keepalived configuration with fail/switchover vIP only if vrrp_script successed on node. And disable failover then vrrp_script not successed.
For example

state1. master(with vIP, vrrp_script successed) - backup(no vIP , vrrp_script failed)

state2.shut master - backup(no vIP, vrrp_script failed)

state3.up master( with vIP, vrrp_script successed ) - backup(no vIP, vrrp_script failed).

But I cant setup such comfiguration. Then master is down, vIP always switched to backup, despite vrrp_script is failed on backup host.

All experiments with weight and priority were unsuccessful(